# Bluebear at the Nocturnal Academy

Tags: zamonia, 13-lives-captain-bluebear

Bluebear turns out not to be the last of his kind, so why does Prof. Nightingale admit him to the Nocturnal Academy?  The reader doesn't know at the point where Bluebear is admitted that he's actually one of a race of colourful bears, but surely a nocturnomath would know.  Or does his uniqueness hang on his exact shade of blue?

Comment: I'd suggest that Zamonia deserves a tag of its own

Comment: It's been a long time since I read it, but was enrollment at the Nocturnal Academy based on how unique a student's species is? According to Wikipedia: "Fellow students include Qwerty Uiop (a gelatine prince from the 2364th Dimension who accidentally fell into this world through a Dimensional Hiatus) and Fredda the Alpine Imp (a hairy creature with a crush on Bluebear)." It sounds like Qwerty, at least, is not unique.

Comment: @user25730 you're right that Qwerty is not unique in all dimensions. However he is unique in the four dimensions in which Zamonia exists because he's the only one to have been pushed into a dimensional hiatus (by Bluebear, of course). It's very puzzling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer this question I will use the German original text of 1999's version at Eichborn Gmbh.

End of chapter 5:

> "Eine Schule?"
>
> "Keine gewöhnliche Schule. Du bist etwas Besonderes. Du mußt den höchsten Bildungsweg gehen, den es gibt. Und den vermittelt nur die Nachtschule."
>
> "Aber das kann ich mir gar nicht leisten!" versuchte ich etwas lahm zu widersprechen. "Ich bin völlig mittellos!"
>
> Mac sah mich mit seinen großen, durchäderten Augen lange an.
>
> "Das macht nichts", sagte er. **"Professor Nachtigaller ist mir etwas schuldig.** Ich habe ihm mal das Leben gerettet. Übrigens in allerletzter Sekunde."

In the English translation:

> 'A school, you mean?'
>
> 'A special school for special individuals like you. You must have the finest education there is, and that you can only get at the Nocturnal Academy.'
>
> 'But I couldn't afford it!" I protested rather feebly.  'I'm completely penniless!'
>
> Mac's bloodshot eyes fixed me with a lingering gaze.
>
> 'That doesn't matter', he said. **'Professor Nightingale owes me.** I saved his life once - in the nick of time, what's more.'

So the professor owes something to Mac because Mac saved his live. This is point one for the theory, that Bluebear could have been admitted outside the exact rules.

Point two is one special wording in the paragraph about the Nocturnal Academy itself (later beginning of chapter 6):

> **Grundsätzlich** nahm Professor Nachtigaller nur Lebewesen auf, von denen es nachweislich nur noch ein einziges Exemplar auf der Welt gab [...]

Here I as native german, see some interpretation. Because the most sentences starting with "grunsätzlich" (in general) will include an "aber" (but) starting the second half of the sentence. This is missing here. So as detectives would say "Important is not only what is there, but also what is missing".

In the English translation, this passage is written as:

> Professor Nightingale made it a rule to only accept life forms of which it could be proved that only one existed on earth...

[So perhaps the nuance was lost in translation. When someone "makes it a rule", there's a possibility of the opposite, but it isn't expected.]

And the last point is the entry in the "Lexikon" (encyclopedia) of the professor (last pages of chapter 13), here he writes "extinction" of the "Buntbären" (Chromobears). So one can assume, that he belives in the possibility Bluebear could be the last of his kind.

Comment: Maybe someone can help me with the appropriate parts from the english version :)

Comment: I can't understand German, but is the second quote "Professor Nightingale made it a rule to only accept life forms of which it could be proved that only one existed on earth"?

Comment: @OutstandingBill yes :) thank you!